# Como fazer um pop-up para inserir um email aparecer ao clicar um botão

Tags: php, html, css

O que eu quero é algo exatamente como nessa página. http://www.movingup.com.br/ Ao clicar em "Quero Assistir" ele abre uma espécie de pop-up pedindo o e-mail.

Comment: Seu problema ficou claro mas, como está o seu código agora? Está usando qual tecnologia? Precisamos de um ponto de partida para lhe ajudar, amigo.

Comment: Olá @DirtyOldMan! Digamos que seria para esse botão..


`<input type="submit" value="lnscrever  Agora!" name="subscribe"      class="call_button">`

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Maicon

Primeiramente, as respostas para a sua pergunta são amplas, então vou te responder usando 2 métodos:

1. Usando apenas CSS + jQuery.
2. Usando uma biblioteca chamada [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

**Usando apenas CSS + jQuery**

Basicamente você vai colocar o código do seu popup (na verdade, é um modal) em alguma parte do seu html, então vai utilizar o jQuery pra manipular quando ele deve ser mostrado/fechado (você também pode fazer isso só com css). Veja aqui o [exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rb8bLcvf/1/).

```
.modal-back {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
.modal-back.toggled {
    display: block;
}
.modal {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 20;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #424242;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.modal a.close {
    float: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Preste atenção na classe **modal-back**, ela é a `div` que guarda o conteúdo do modal, bem como preenche toda a tela pra dar um foco no conteúdo apresentado. Ela nunca ficará visível até ser usada em conjunto com a classe **toggled**. Altere os valores do atributo `z-index` caso em sua página algum elemento html fique "na frente" do modal, mas lembre-se que a classe **modal** sempre deverá ter um `z-index` maior que a classe **modal-back**.

Ok, mas como mostro o modal/popup?

Veja o código html:

```
<button type="button" id="mostrar-msg">Assistir</button>

<div id="modal-assistir" class="modal-back">
    <div class="modal">
        <a class="close" href="#" data-toggle="modal-assistir">Fechar</a>
        <form>
            <label for="email">Insira seu email para assistir</label>
            <br>
            <input type="email" name="email">
            <br><br>
            <button type="button">Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

E nosso código javascript/jQuery:

```
$('#mostrar-msg').click(function() {
    $('#modal-assistir').addClass('toggled');
});

$('a.close').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = '#' + $(this).data('toggle');
    $(target).removeClass('toggled');
});
```

Nós definimos um `id` ao botão que abre o modal e usamos esse id pra mostrar o modal que queremos, adicionando a classe **toggled**.

A parte `$('a.close').click(function(e) ...` trata de fechar o modal/popup aberto, usando o atributo `data-toggle` do link, que **deve ser igual ao id do modal/popup**.

<sub>Nota: esse é um exemplo super simples, pode apresentar bugs e defeitos, procurando por "modal pure css" ou coisa do tipo você acha muitos outros exemplos melhores.</sub>

[**Usando o Bootstrap**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

O Bootstrap é uma biblioteca muito utilizada por aí, eu amo ela (<3). E com ela nossa tarefa fica muito mais fácil. Veja aqui [um exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/31zzg6Lv/).

Nós nem precisaremos lidar com jQuery ou javascript agora, apenas precisamos definir um elemento que abra nosso modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

Utilizamos os atributos `data-toggle="modal"` e `data-toggle="#id-do-modal"`.

No final da sua página, antes da tag `</body>` ou então dos scripts js coloque o código html do modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

O conteúdo que você quer apresentar no modal deve ser alterado aqui.