# Mensagem ao entrar na página

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de que quando alguém entrasse na minha página, abrisse uma `box`, mas não queria que fosse a padrão do navegador, mas sim uma escolhida a partir do meu `CSS`.

Isso seria possível?

**Códigos:**

```css
.box {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

---

Eu queria também, que ao abrir a box, o fundo ficasse tipo mais escuro, em volta, e quando fechasse ficava a página normal...

Comment: Chamar no ready do document não serve?

Comment: Abrir onde? Você quer fazer um Modal?

Comment: Se ela vai aparecer *sempre* que a página for carregada porquê não deixa ela com visualização fixa e se preocupa apenas em adicionar um botão "Fechar" á mensagem? É mais prático.

Comment: Eu queria que toda vez que a pessoa entrasse na página aparecesse, e que tivesse um botão de fechar. Mas o botão de fechar eu já tenho, só queria para abrir toda vez que entrasse na página.

Comment: O que você quer é um `modal`, dê uma olhada nessa resposta que fiz em outra pergunta, ela atende sua dúvida: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65881/como-fazer-um-pop-up-para-inserir-um-email-aparecer-ao-clicar-um-bot%C3%A3o/65887#65887

Comment: Não resolveu, o modal fica sem estilo e quando tenta fechar, não acontece nada. Já tentei na bootstrap também.

Comment: Herman o bootstrap requer jquery, será que você esqueceu de adiciona-lo?

Comment: Eu consegui o modal. mas tem que clicar em "Open Modal" para abrir. Eu queria que quando a pessoa entrasse na página, automaticamente abria...

Answer (score 1):

Use a função onLoad do JS.

```
document.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('box').style.display = 'block'; 
};


<div id="box"></div>

#box {
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    width:500px;
    height: 500px;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Da uma olhada na biblioteca [sweetalert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/). Depois que você instalar ela, basta chamar um `swal` (que é o método principal da biblioteca) quando o documento estiver pronto:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    swal('Minha mensagem');
}):
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), `$.ready` e `$(...).modal('show');`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```